# How to delay a live stream?

Tags: go

I'm trying to build a service in Go which delays a live stream (socketio/signalR) for ~7 minutes. It should also allow a non-delayed stream. So the Go service should have something like a buffer or a queue that forces data to wait for the specified duration before it is allowed to be consumed. How would you do something like this in Go? Would the delayed stream be a seperate goroutine? What data structure should be used to delay the data?

My current idea would be to use the `time` package to wait/tick for 7 minutes before the data is allowed to be consumed but this blocking behavior might not be optimal in this scenario.

Here is some code to explain what I'm trying to do. `FakeStream` is a mock function that simulates the live streamed data I'm getting from the external service.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func DelayStream(input chan string, output chan string, delay string) {

    // not working for some reason
    // delayDuration, _ := time.ParseDuration(delay)
    // fmt.Println(delayDuration.Seconds())

    if delay == "5s" {
        fmt.Println("sleeping")
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
    data := <-input
    output <- data
}

func FakeStream(live chan string) {

    ticks := time.Tick(2 * time.Second)
    for now := range ticks {
        live <- fmt.Sprintf("%v", now.Format(time.UnixDate))
    }
}

func main() {
    liveData := make(chan string)
    delayedData := make(chan string)

    go FakeStream(liveData)
    go DelayStream(liveData, delayedData, "5s")

    for {
        select {
        case live := <-liveData:
            fmt.Println("live: ", live)
        case delayed := <-delayedData:
            fmt.Println("delayed: ", delayed)
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the delayed channel only outputs once and it doesn't output the expected data. It should output the first thing in the live channel but it doesn't.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet to make your methodology clearer to people around here?

Comment: Adding a delay to code is easy. Write something, when you get stuck, then ask here, and include your code.

Comment: @flimzy Added some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a buffer of sufficient size. For simple cases, a buffered Go channel could work.

Ask yourself - how much data is there to store during this delay - you should have a reasonable upper cap. For example if your stream delivers up to N packets per second, then to delay by 7 minutes you'll need to store 420N packets.

Ask yourself - what happens if more data than expected arrives during the delay window? You can throw the new data away, or throw the old data away, or just block the input stream. Which of these are feasible for your scenario? Each results in a slightly different solution.

Ask yourself - how is the delay computed? From the moment the stream is created? From the moment each packet arrives? Is the delay for each packet separately, or only for the first packet in the stream?

You'll need to considerably narrow down the design choices here in order to develop some sample code.

For some subset of these design choices, here's a simple way to add delay between channels for each message:

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // in is a channel of strings with a buffer size of 10
    in := make(chan string, 10)

    // out is an unbuffered channel
    out := make(chan string)

    // this goroutine forwards messages from in to out, ading a delay
    // to each message.
    const delay = 3 * time.Second
    go func() {
        for msg := range in {
            time.Sleep(delay)
            out <- msg
        }
        close(out)
    }()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    // this goroutine drains the out channel
    go func() {
        for msg := range out {
            fmt.Printf("Got '%s' at time %s\n", msg, time.Now().Format(time.Stamp))
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    // Send some messages into the in channel
    fmt.Printf("Sending '%s' at time %s\n", "joe", time.Now().Format(time.Stamp))
    in <- "joe"

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("Sending '%s' at time %s\n", "hello", time.Now().Format(time.Stamp))
    in <- "hello"

    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("Sending '%s' at time %s\n", "bye", time.Now().Format(time.Stamp))
    in <- "bye"
    close(in)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you're using the WaitGroup?

Comment: waitGroups are a key tool for coordinating go-routines. In the above case, tracing the `wg` references, the main function will not exit, until the `go func()` go-routine has completed. In a standalone executable example like this, this is crucial, as the program will just quickly exit - if the main go-routine exits. In this example the delay go-routine is still running - so it's polite to let it finish.

Comment: @colminator But why does the first goroutine ignore this?

Comment: go-routines are completely independent by design. For a useful program, one needs coordination. Go-routines can communicate via channels, waitGroups, locks etc., or not at all - it's up to you.

Comment: Also how would I change this to allow two functions to read from the same channel? As mentioned in the OP, the live data should also be streamed. My current solution is not working too well.

Comment: I assume from the OP description that you want both reader to receive the same stream. If that is the case, have multiple readers reading from the same channel will not work - as each go-routine will get individual events - but never the same event. To fix this, you would need a pub/sub model. Still possible with channels, but you'd need a the master channel to be read by a master go-routine - and it in turn writes each event to subscriber channels, to ensure delivery of all _events_ to all _listeners_.